# Which method is called or How to handle when remote push notification arrives when app is killed manually

Tags: ios, swift, push

App remote notification work well when app is foreground or background state but not works when App is killed manually,

Added background fetch in plist.

Tried with:

```
 NSLog("Do something")
```

under this method still not able to receive in swift :

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
```

and

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you kill the app manually, the remoteNotifications cannot be handled before the app is launched again.

When a remote notification is present, and you open the app by tapping on that notification, the app launches in the usual manner with the

```
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
```

method being called in the app delegate. But in this case, your notification data would be passed in the 'Options' parameter. You can then check for this parameter and perform the required tasks

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{

    if (launchOptions != nil)
    {
        let dictionary:NSDictionary = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as! NSDictionary
        self.setNotification(dictionary)
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot handle a push notifications while app is not running. You only can handle when a user open the app form notification.
There is good article about that: [How to handle remote notification with background mode enabled](http://samwize.com/2015/08/07/how-to-handle-remote-notification-with-background-mode-enabled/)